# Google App Engine is consistently returning 400 response to non-custom domain

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

My use case is a Django app running in an app-engine service and I am using cloud tasks to execute async work in the background.

Django creates task -> task posts back to Django to execute long-running task

That post back is consistently encountering a `400` response from the server.  After looking through the logs it appears that it is posting back a relative url with the host being the default google given domain i.e. `sample-development-app.uc.r.appspot.com`.  When I navigate to that location in the browser I also encounter a 400 response.

However, I have a custom domain set up and working on this application i.e. `app.development.sample.com`.  When I navigate to this location in a browser I get the expected webpage.

I have tried mapping both urls with a `dispatch.yaml` to the same default service, but that didn't change the result.  My working assumption is that the task postback is encountering the same issue I am seeing in the browser.

This is my first project on gcp app engine, so I am thinking I am missing something in a menu someplace to allow it to accept multiple urls, one of them being the default google supplied one.

Thanks for reading this far.

app.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
# [START gaestd_py_django_app_yaml]
runtime: python310

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings.gae

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: config/staticfiles/

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
- url: "sample-development-app.uc.r.appspot.com/*"
  service: default
- url: "app.development.sample.com/*"
  service: default
```

Comment: Does your service have a version? If so, you should be using the ```dot``` and not ```.```  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-requests-are-routed?tab=python#example_urls

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I figured it out, and it was something stilly.

Answer (score 0):

I will own my issue, it turned out that the "ALLOWED_HOSTS" was set to the custom domain URL.  From the logs, it appeared that the application wasn't being accessed but it was in fact just a silly mistake.